# Will push ups, pull ups, sit ups and interval training get me ripped?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, interval-training

I hardly have any time at all, so I'm considering doing push ups, pull ups, sit ups and interval training every Monday, Wednesday and Friday morning. Then once I can do a certain amount of each I will either add weight to the exercise or try a harder variation.

Is this routine effective to reach my goal of a getting ripped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, see [The 60-Day Challenge](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/plp_the_60day_challenge).

It will get you to a base level of strength, and help burn fat – assuming you don't overcompensate with the amount of food you eat.

However, I would look into body weight exercises to help the rest of your body.  For example:

- Dips
- Pistols
- Back extensions
- Glute-ham raises
- Reverse rows

When you get strong enough you can combine the pullups and dips into a [muscle up](http://beastskills.com/tutorials/tutorials/53). (which can also be performed with a straight bar).

Body weight exercises are compound exercises, which means they exercise a group of related muscles together.  That helps build strength.  Having started incorporating more body weight exercises I'm gaining even more respect for them.  However, you do want to keep major muscle groups involved:

- Core (abs and back)
- Legs (both front and back: pistols)
- Back (pullups and muscleups, reverse rows, back extensions)
- Front (pushups)

Your arms will get more than enough attention from all of these exercises, so you really don't have to do anything special for them.

Answer (score 2):

To get real ripped improve your diet. More protein and cut all the bad stuff (you know what they are..). 75% of your muscles come from the kitchen :)

Talking from experience. Have Fun!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main things you have to concentrate on when trying to get ripped. The most important thing are diet, cardio, and weight training.

If you are not prepared to change your diet then don't try to become ripped. Less carbs and more protein and taking less than 2500 calories a day for men. For women, 1800 calories will lead you on the right track to getting the body you always wanted.

Cardio is just as important as diet! You might already have a six pack but your fat will be covering it. Cardio reveals your lean body. You want to try to get about 40 minutes of cardio in a day. Skipping is my most highly rated cardio activity and is one of the fastest fat burning exercises. 10 minutes of high intensity skipping is the same as 30 minutes of jogging.

Weight training is also important because your muscles will get bigger than more you train. They will also show more after doing lost of cardio so hiting the gym will make sure you gain and not lose muscle.

Comment: Less than 2500 calories per day? Thats not going to work for strength training.

Comment: As if every person needs the same amount of calories…

Comment: Needed calorie intakes are averages. Actual calorie intake needed is different for every individual depending on activity. Body fat percentages would be more useful to this person, because without low body fat percentages, you'll never look ripped... but if you go too low, you'll do your health a disservice.